# Изменение размера изображения jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Всем привет! Такой вопрос, у меня есть изображения, я вывожу их таким образом http://cash-back.kz/index.php/products/cat/komp_yuternaya_tehnika/date можете посмотреть слева эти изображения.

Я вывожу их через цикл, и возникла нужда, выровнить все строчки в одинаковую высоту. Сейчас я все изображения беру и ставлю им width:140px, а высота автоматически. Получается то что когда высота больше ширины то по высоте колонке становится большой как 4 и 5 продукт по ссылке.

Нужно сделать так, наверно через jquery. Если высота больше ширины то изменять в изображении не width, а height. Если ширина больше высоты то так же как и сейчас ставить width.

p.s Изначально изображения на сервер загружается в разных размерах, только при выводе я ставлю width и height. Подскажите как реализовать? Спасибоо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю как насчет кроссбраузерности, но штука вполне [решается](http://jsfiddle.net/47DFd/) через css:

```
.example-image-link {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px; 
  line-height: 150px; 
  text-align: center;
}
.example-image-link img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
}
```